# List of Dictionary to multidimensional array

Tags: .net, vb.net, dictionary, multidimensional-array

I am trying to pass a list of files and paths to a third party method that accepts only a String(,).  this selection can vary depending on the users selections.

I thought the following would represent then 2D array, holding the path and the name of the files.

```
myFiles As New List(Of Dictionary(Of String, String))()
```

But when I have to pass this to the method for example

```
ProcessFiles(ByVal Attachments(,) As String)
```

With

```
 ProcessFiles(myFiles.ToArray())
```

I get the error

> "Value of 'Dictionary(Of String, string)() cannot be converted to a
>   String(*,*) because the array types have different numbers of
>   dimensions.

How do I define my List to be representative of the array?

The array is expecting a layout of

```
(0,0) --> "\\location\Of\File"
(0,1) --> "filename"
(1,0) --> "\\location\Of\File2"
(1,1) --> "filename2"
```

Comment: The Dictionary key goes in `Attachments(X, )` then the value into   `Attachments( , Y)`?  `ToArray` on a Dictionary (which itself is 2 collections) wont do that.

Comment: So then what collection would work?  the Attachments(,) is representative of  (0,0) should be path (0,1) the name, (1,0) path and (1,1) as name.   Since i do not know the # of files to begin with, i was hoping performing a list toArray would solve it.

Comment: Since your Dictionary is inside a list, ToArray is just going to return an Array of Dictionaries.  There might be a linqy way, but you could just iterate the list and copy each KVP to the destination

Comment: I am suddenly rethinking my list of dictionary.  what my intention here is to get a clean collection to easily convert into the array.  Can ToArray be used for a 2D array in VB?  Sorry new to all of this, inherited something old but new to me.

Comment: I/we have no context at all and no idea what the data looks like.  How many pairs are there in those dictionaries - are they all just 1 key/value pair or are they actual collections.  There is no `To2DArray()` method so the answer depends on the data

Comment: There is a screen where users can select up to 100 plus files, I gather up the filenames and paths and then put them into any collection that would make the job of converting them to the array within the Processfiles method.  i will edit the question to help

Comment: You also can't use a dictionary to hold paths which could be duplicate, if I understand that correctly. i.e. "\\location\Of\File\filename", "\\location\Of\File\filename2"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a relatively simple solution (which is essentially what Plutonix suggested) assuming each dictionary only has 1 value and that the dictionary key is the path and value is the name:

```
    ' temporary dictionary for loop iteration
    Dim currentDict As Dictionary(Of String, String)
    ' assuming each dictionary only has 1 path/name entry, set up 2D string array
    Dim myFileArray(,) As String = New String(myFiles.Count - 1, 1) {}

    ' assuming the dictionary key is the path and the dictionary value is the name, 
    ' iterate through myFiles and extract key/value into 2D array
    For i = 0 To myFiles.Count - 1
        currentDict = myFiles(i)
        myFileArray(i, 0) = currentDict.Keys(0)
        myFileArray(i, 1) = currentDict.Values(1)
    Next

    ProcessFiles(myFileArray)
```

I played around with some LINQ queries, but .ToArray yields jagged arrays (which are not the same as multidimensional arrays), so it might not be possible/practical to go that route if you absolutely need a 2D array.

Comment: yes thats it.  One little note myFileArray(i, 1) = currentDict.Values(1) should be myFileArray(i, 1) = currentDict.Values(0).  i was inccorectly handling the myFiles(i) on my end.

Answer (score 1):

Accepted answer is in general a way to handle it.

However, if you have duplicate directories (i.e. two files in the same directory), you can't use a directory as a key to a dictionary, because the key must be unique.

A `List(Of` ... `KeyValuePair`, `struct`, `Tuple`, `custom class`, or `existing class` `)` would get around the collision.

*`List(Of KeyValuePair)` is close to Dictionary in that they expose `KeyValuePair` when Enumerated, and you could simply replace `Dictionary(Of String, String)` in garthhh's answer with `List(Of KeyValuePair(String, String))` to avoid collisions.*

Specifically, I think `System.IO.FileInfo` might be a class for your case, since you are working with files. So, using a `List(Of System.IO.FileInfo)` ...

```
Dim myFileListFileInfo As New List(Of System.IO.FileInfo) From {
    New FileInfo(System.IO.Path.Combine("\\location\Of\File", "filename")),
    New FileInfo(System.IO.Path.Combine("\\location\Of\File2", "filename2")),
    New FileInfo(System.IO.Path.Combine("\\location\Of\File3", "filename3"))
} ' initialize this way...
' ... or add like this
myFileListFileInfo.Add(New FileInfo(System.IO.Path.Combine("\\location\Of\File4", "filename4")))
Dim myFileArray(myFileListFileInfo.Count - 1, 1) As String
For i = 0 To myFileListFileInfo.Count - 1
    myFileArray(i, 0) = myFileListFileInfo(i).DirectoryName
    myFileArray(i, 1) = myFileListFileInfo(i).Name
Next
```

Or maybe it's overkill if you really just want an array(,). As I said, you could use a number of things in place of FileInfo from classes, Tuples, etc.